# Will try-catch catch an error if the function inside of it doesn't have an await in front of it?

Tags: javascript

Imagine I have the following function:

```
const test = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('testurl');
    return response;
}
```

And then I try to use the function like this:

```
try {
    test();
} catch (error) {
    // handle errors
}
```

Will the try-catch block actually catch the error if I call the test() function without an await in front of it in the try-catch block?

Comment: No. If you're not awaiting you need to .catch the error.

Comment: No, it won't catch error that way. If you have problem to await, because code is in something that can't be async you can add iife to solve this problem (async () => {
    try {
        }
    } catch (e) {
        // this should catch all exceptions
    }
})();

Comment: @jonrsharpe I could also add an await in front of the function and the functionality wouldn't change right?

Comment: No, `await` *does* change the functionality. If it did nothing, then it wouldn't have been added. The whole point of `await` is to *wait* until an async value is finally present. In this case an async function call finishes.

Comment: Then I should just do test().catch((error) => { // handle error })

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Without an `await` the calling function will not go to sleep and wait for the promise to resolve or error. It will continue running to its own completion.

Later, when the promise errors, the error will be unhandled.